# Typescript Error Putting Classes in Separate Files

Tags: javascript, oop, typescript, typeerror

I feel like this is a really basic mistake I'm making, but I can't find the solution anywhere. I have two classes, Moo.ts:

```
module namespace {
export class Moo{
    constructor() {
        //   window.console.log("hello from Moo");
        var foo:Foo = new Foo();
    }
}
```

and Foo.ts:

```
 module namespace {
export class Foo{
    constructor() {
        //   window.console.log("hello from Foo");
    }
}
```

When running Moo.ts I would expect it to make an instance of Foo, but it doesn't. It give this error:

> TypeError: namespace.Foo is not a constructor

It works fine when I put the two classes in the same ts file, but when I break them up everything falls apart. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You probably included the `Foo.js` (The generated file) in your html after `Moo.js`, this means that when `Moo.js` run (As it was the first js file) it did not find **namespace.Foo**

The order of including the generated js files is important. That's why you'd better use the [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/wiki/tsconfig.json) and include one generated js file in your html (You can use source-maps to debug the TypeScript code)